# How to ensure table is on a certain page

Tags: tables, floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/keeping-tables-figures-close-to-where-they-are-mentioned)

I have a doc that has several tables in it.  Each section of my end document is in a separate .tex file.  In some of my files I have tables in them.  Say, for example, section 4 has two tables.  Currently the first table for section four does not begin on any of the pages that section 4 is on.  Section 5 starts at the end of the last page, but the first section 4 table appears on the next page, which does not have any of the section 4 text in it.  How do I ensure these tables appear on pages that have section 4 text on them?

Comment: See [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764) on ways of how to make floats stay where you want them to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For general advice look at [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat). For your specific problem you might try to use the `\FloatBarrier` command (from the package `placeins`) which will output all floats that are not yet typeset when encountered. E.g.,

```
\usepackage{placeins}

... 
\Floatbarrier
\section{New section}
```

The package offers some fine-tuning possibilities, see its documentation.